# How do you add a UILabel to a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uilabel

I'm trying to add a UILabel to a UIScrollView. I followed the steps in [this](http://www.planet1107.net/blog/tips-tutorials/how-to-create-uilabel-inside-of-uiscrollview-programmatically/) tutorial. But for some reason, the label is not showing on the scrollView when I run the app. The app consists of a storyboard with two files (*ViewController.h* and *ViewController.m*). In the storyboard there's only one view controller which is a custom class of *ViewController*. Below is my code which is in the ViewDidLoad method of *ViewController.m*.

```
UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 150.0, 250.0)];
testLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[testLabel sizeToFit];
testLabel.text = @"test";

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)];

[scrollView addSubview:testLabel];
```

I tried the following lines of code at the end of my current, but still doesn't help.

```
[testLabel release];
[scrollView release];
```

Comment: add the scrollView to the view `[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `[testLabel sizeToFit]` before setting the text. This is setting the size of the label's `frame` to 0, 0.

Call `sizeToFit` *after* setting the text.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the view adds the scrollView as a subview too.

And a word to your fixes. Since Objective-C supports ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) the call "release" is not needed anymore.